# K8s Error: ImagePullBackOff || read: connection refused

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-devops

Can you please assist when deploying we getting ImagePullBackOff for our pods.

running `kubectl get <pod-name> -n namespace -o yaml` am getting below error.

```yaml
containerStatuses:
  - image: mycontainer-registry.io/company/my-app:1.0.0-integration-62c7e30532bd430477731a01a962372166fd5644
    imageID: ""
    lastState: {}
    name: dmd-base
    ready: false
    restartCount: 0
    started: false
    state:
      waiting:
        message: Back-off pulling image "mycontainer-registry.io/company/my-app:1.0.0-integration-62c7e30532bd430477731a01a962372166fd5644"
        reason: ImagePullBackOff
  hostIP: x.x.x.53
  phase: Pending
  podIP: x.x.x.237
```

and running `kubectl describe pod <pod-name> -n namespace` am getting below error infomation

```
  Normal   Scheduled  85m                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned dmd-int/app-app-base-5b4b75756c-lrcp6 to aks-agentpool-35064155-vmss00000a
  Warning  Failed     85m                  kubelet            Failed to pull image "mycontainer-registry.io/company/my-app:1.0.0-integration-62c7e30532bd430477731a01a962372166fd5644": 
  [rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "mycontainer-registry.io/company/my-app:1.0.0-integration-62c7e30532bd430477731a01a962372166fd5644": 
  failed to resolve reference "mycontainer-registry.io/commpany/my-app:1.0.0-integration-62c7e30532bd430477731a01a962372166fd5644": 
  failed to do request: Head "https://mycontainer-registry.azurecr.io/v2/company/my-app/manifests/1.0.0-integration-62c7e30532bd430477731a01a962372166fd5644": 
  dial tcp: lookup mycontainer-registry.azurecr.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:56109->[::1]:53: read: connection refused, 
  rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "mycontainer-registry.io/company/my-app:1.0.0-integration-62c7e30532bd430477731a01a962372166fd5644": 
  failed to resolve reference "mycontainer-registry.io/company/my-app:1.0.0-integration-62c7e30532bd430477731a01a962372166fd5644": 
  failed to do request: Head "https://mycontainer-registry.io/v2/company/my-app/manifests/1.0.0-integration-62c7e30532bd430477731a01a962372166fd5644": 
  dial tcp: lookup mycontainer-registry.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:60759->[::1]:53: read: connection refused]`
```

From the described logs I can see the issue is a connection but I can't tell where the issue is with connectivity, we running our apps in a Kubernetes cluster on Azure.

If anyone has come across this issue can you please assist the application has been running successfully throughout the past months we just got this issue this morning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a known Azure outage multiple regions today.
Some DNS issue that also affects image pulls.
https://status.azure.com/en-us/status

Comment: Thanks, @Andreas, will keep an eye on the status and workaround.